# DropDownList cannot set DataTextField on GridViewSelectedIndexChangedEvent

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Designation` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TblDesignation
(
    [DesgId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TblDesignation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DesgId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Employee.aspx page code:

```
 <div id="divView" align="center" runat="server" >
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpId" HeaderText="EMP ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpFirstName" HeaderText="FIRST NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpMiddleName" HeaderText="MIDDLE NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpLastName" HeaderText="LAST NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpGender" HeaderText="GENDER" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpDesignation" HeaderText="DESIGNATION" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpAddress" HeaderText="ADDRESS" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpEmailId" HeaderText="EMAIL ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpContactNo" HeaderText="CONTACT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpDOB" HeaderText="D.O.B" dataformatstring="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MSAMBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TblEmployee]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddNew" runat="server" Text="ADD NEW EMPLOYEE" 
        onclick="btnAddNew_Click" />
</div>
<div id="divForm" runat="server"  style="margin-top:4%;">
<table border="2" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpId" runat="server" Text="EMP ID"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpId" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpFirstName" runat="server" Text="FIRST NAME : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpMiddleName" runat="server" Text="MIDDLE NAME : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpMiddleName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpLastName" runat="server" Text="LAST NAME : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblGender" runat="server" Text="GENDER : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbMale" runat="server" Text="Male" GroupName="Gender" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbFemale" runat="server" Text="Female" GroupName="Gender" />
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpDesignation" runat="server" Text="DESIGNATION : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddrDesgn" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
        DataTextField="Designation" DataValueField="DesgId" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddrDesgn_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    **<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MSAMBConnectionString3 %>
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TblDesignation]"></asp:SqlDataSource>**

</td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpAddress" runat="server" Text="ADDRESS : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpEmailId" runat="server" Text="EMAIL ID : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpEmailId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpContactNo" runat="server" Text="CONTACT NO : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpContactNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmpDOB" runat="server" Text="DOB : "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpDOB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtEmpDOB_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtEmpDOB">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1" align="center">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="SAVE" 
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" /></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" 
                onclick="btnUpdate_Click" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Employee.aspx">BACK</asp:HyperLink>
    </td>

    </tr>


</table>

</div>
```

Employee.aspx.cs C# Code:

```
On protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text == "Male")
        {
            rbMale.Checked = true;
        }
        else {
            rbFemale.Checked = true;
        }
        txtEmpId.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        txtEmpFirstName.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        txtEmpMiddleName.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
        txtEmpLastName.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
        ddrDesgn.DataTextField = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
        txtEmpAddress.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;
        txtEmpEmailId.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;
        txtEmpContactNo.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text;
        txtEmpDOB.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text;
        divView.Visible = false;
        divForm.Visible = true;

    }
```

It gives me error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'MD'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.    
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'MD'.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your grid thinks your trying to bind to a something called 'MD' when no such things exists in the source data, although I can't see in in your code, try this go to visual studio, Server Exolorer (Ctrl-Alt-S) create a connection to your DB, navigate to your table, ensure your are in GUI mode on your ASP page, then drag the table onto the page, VS will auto-generate the SQL and the Gridview, from there you should be able to add / remove columns using the datasource or the grid until you get what u need.

Comment: in CS code i have Connection string like this..
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);


and on ASPX PAGE  dropdoenlist bind with table like this...

Comment: Your questions say I have a Designation table: but your code is doing  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  in gridview and your SQL code is going to SELECT * FROM [TblEmployee] in Datasource 1, further down the page you have SqlDataSource2 which contains SELECT * FROM [TblDesignation] , I think you need to change datasource, change the ID property of Gridview1 to DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"

Comment: ok but in gridview i hav to show all records from TblEmployee and in dropdownlist it shows designation from TblDesignation table...

Comment: The dropdownlist needs to be inside a template in your grid http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx